# R package RcppArmadillo "has a configure script" and "probably needs manual configuration"

Tags: r, rcpparmadillo

I just updated my R packages packages in RStudio. For the RcppArmadillo package (version 0.11.4.3.1), RStudio warned me that no binary package is available for my system (x86_64, Windows 11) and asked if I wanted to install the source package instead. Since I have RTools installed for just this purpose, I said yes.

The installation succeeded, but a warning was issued that the package "has a configure script" and "probably needs manual configuration".

```
* installing *source* package 'RcppArmadillo' ...
** package 'RcppArmadillo' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/.../R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I../inst/include -I. -fopenmp    -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c RcppArmadillo.cpp -o RcppArmadillo.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/.../R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I../inst/include -I. -fopenmp    -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++  -std=gnu++11 -I"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'C:/.../R/win-library/4.2/Rcpp/include'   -I"C:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/include"  -I../inst/include -I. -fopenmp    -O2 -Wall  -mfpmath=sse -msse2 -mstackrealign  -c fastLm.cpp -o fastLm.o
g++ -shared -s -static-libgcc -o RcppArmadillo.dll tmp.def RcppArmadillo.o RcppExports.o fastLm.o -fopenmp -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/bin/x64 -lRlapack -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/bin/x64 -lRblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/x64 -LC:/rtools42/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib -LC:/PROGRA~1/R/R-42~1.2/bin/x64 -lR
installing to C:/.../R/win-library/4.2/00LOCK-RcppArmadillo/00new/RcppArmadillo/libs/x64
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (RcppArmadillo)
```

My questions are:

1. Should I be concerned?
2. How can I tell that the package is working correctly?
3. If manual configuration *is* needed, how do I do it?

An aside for the second of those: I'm not using this package directly, and presume that it was installed as a dependency of another package that I used in the past. Since I do not remember which package that may have been (or when I last used it), I can't just dig into my older code, find a script that uses this package, and see if it still works.

Is there such a thing in the R world as automated tests to ensure that a newly-compiled package actually works before it gets installed? I'm a little surprised that this is apparently not done by default.

Comment: I'm not an expert but I don't think you want to be using mingw32, try mingw64

Comment: Good observation. I just installed the RTools version available on CRAN, but that was a while ago and may itself be outdated by now. I'll update.

Comment: If that was the problem then you might want to report back in the form of an answer and mark it solved. I searched for  duplicate on SO and Rhelp and could not find one. I seem to remember that  Windows R abandoned 32 bit arch a few years ago.

Comment: @IRTFM you're right; but unfortunately it wasn't. Turns out my RTools version was already the latest and greatest; in any case this should have no bearing on whether the package "has a configure script" etc.

Comment: So what happens when you build something?

Comment: @IRTFM see above. I don't build things myself using RTools; I only have it installed so that I can install source packages when no binary is available (yet).